# Blank screen is shown when xceed datagrid is loaded in model dialog(pop-up) in wpf application

Tags: xceed, xceed-datagrid

I am showing DataGrid on my model dialog(popup). We are using WPF for showing xceed DataGrid. But sometimes instead of data blanks screen is shown. This is happening randomly, and we are not able to reproduce this issue. I tried by adding try catch but no exception is catched. Even there is no error in event manager,

This issue is happening on some specific machines. I have no clue why I am getting this error. Even I am not able to reproduce this because this is happening randomly.

My project is very large and so i cant send sample application.

Any help or suggestion is most welcome and please reply as this is a critical issue for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi This problem occurs if you are loading your data in UI Thread.
If the size of data is large then UI thread will be blocked and blank screen will be rendered by WPF.

Use background worker to bind your data.